# Android PNG Transparency Issue

Tags: android, png

I'm using PNG images with transparency in my game and no matter what I do the edges of them get all grainy looking.

I have tried setting the following in my activity with no luck:

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);

Is there anything I can do in Photoshop or in my game to overcome this. Please see the image here:
[image: Play button]

Comment: I believe the problem is with your image, not with the android and transparency.

Comment: I agree with Draiken's comment, Android isn't doing this. I have buttons with transparency that work quite well. Maybe describe your creation process. You may also need to consider requesting help in a photoshop forum rather than here.

Comment: Why does the image look great everywhere else except in Android?

Comment: I am using PimapFormat ARGB8888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your image is too low a resolution and the edges are not tidy, there is some white left over from when you deleted the background.

Open the image in photoshop, zoom right in and fix your edges. Probably best to redraw and resize again for the screen you are using.